# Post content stream gets bufferend when using compression on content-block

Tags: .net, vb.net, compression, streaming, sendasync

**First to what works:** (the description of my problem further down)

A client application sends a long data-stream to the server WebAPI.
The request is chunked (`request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = True`) and the data gets written to the stream "on the fly".

The data consists of serialized objects, each representing the custom class `Chunk`.

Everything works fine, the server can start to read the stream before the client is done writing (server input buffering disabled for the controller).

*Starting the request:*

```
Public Async Function Transfer(authCookie As Cookie) As Task

    Using handler As New HttpClientHandler()
        handler.CookieContainer = New Net.CookieContainer
        handler.CookieContainer.Add(authCookie)

        'Client instance
        Using client As New HttpClient(handler), content As New Content(AddressOf WriteToStream)

            'Send stream asynchronously
            Dim request As New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://myserver.net/api/datastream")
            request.Content = content
            request.Headers.TransferEncodingChunked = True

            Await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ContinueWith(
                Async Function(requestTask)
                    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Nothing
                    Try
                        response = Await requestTask
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        'Exception writing the stream
                        Exit Function
                    End Try
                    Try
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        'Exception on server ocurred
                    End Try

                    response.RequestMessage.Dispose()
                    response.Dispose()
                End Function)

        End Using
    End Using

End Function

Public Sub WriteToStream(str As IO.Stream)

    'Head-chunk
    head.attachedChunks.CompleteAdding()

    'Write head-chunk to stream
    Task.Run(
        Async Function()
            Await head.WriteToStream(str)
        End Function).Wait()

End Sub
```

*HttpContent Class:*

```
Public Class Content
    Inherits Net.Http.HttpContent

    Protected ReadOnly actionOfStream As Action(Of IO.Stream)

    Public Sub New(action As Action(Of IO.Stream))
        If action Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("action")
        actionOfStream = action
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function SerializeToStreamAsync(stream As IO.Stream, context As Net.TransportContext) As Task

        Return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            Sub(obj)
                Dim target As IO.Stream = DirectCast(obj, IO.Stream)
                actionOfStream(target)
            End Sub,
            stream)

    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function TryComputeLength(ByRef length As Long) As Boolean
        length = -1
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```

The method `WriteToStream()` calls the Head-chunks `WriteToStream()`, which calls the same method for its sub-chunks:

```
Public Class Chunk

    'More properties here

    Public Property attachedChunks As BlockingCollection(Of Chunk)

    Public Overridable Async Function WriteToStream(str As IO.Stream) As Task

        Using serializationStream As New IO.MemoryStream

            'Serialize
            Serializer.Serialize(Of Chunk)(serializationStream, Me)

            'Write length
            Dim cnt As Integer = CInt(serializationStream.Length)
            Dim cntBuffer() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(cnt)
            Await str.WriteAsync(cntBuffer, 0, cntBuffer.Length)

            'Write chunk
            serializationStream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Await serializationStream.CopyToAsync(str)

        End Using

        Await str.FlushAsync()

        'Clearing and disposing stuff 
        '...

        'Write sub-chunks
        If attachedChunks IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each chunk As Chunk In attachedChunks.GetConsumingEnumerable
                Await chunk.WriteToStream(str)
            Next

            attachedChunks.Dispose()
        End If

        'Write ending mark
        If attachedChunksIndefiniteCount Then
            Await str.WriteAsync({0, 0, 0, 0}, 0, 4)
        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

So far so good.

**The problem** comes when I start using a compression like GZipStream to compress my Chunk: the request gets buffered on client side, so it seams.

Here's the `WriteToStream()` method of the `Chunk`-class:

```
Public Class Chunk

    'More properties here

    Public Property attachedChunks As BlockingCollection(Of Chunk)

    Public Overridable Async Function WriteToStream(str As IO.Stream) As Task

        Using serializationStream As New IO.MemoryStream

            'Serialization and compression
            Using gZipStream As New IO.Compression.GZipStream(serializationStream, IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, True)
                Using bufferStream As New IO.BufferedStream(gZipStream, 64 * 1024)

                    'Serialize
                    Serializer.Serialize(Of Chunk)(bufferStream, Me)

                End Using
            End Using

            'Write length
            Dim cnt As Integer = CInt(serializationStream.Length)
            Dim cntBuffer() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(cnt)
            Await str.WriteAsync(cntBuffer, 0, cntBuffer.Length)

            'Write chunk
            serializationStream.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
            Await serializationStream.CopyToAsync(str)

        End Using

        Await str.FlushAsync()

        'Clearing and disposing stuff 
        '...

        'Write sub-chunks
        If attachedChunks IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each chunk As Chunk In attachedChunks.GetConsumingEnumerable
                Await chunk.WriteToStream(str)
            Next

            attachedChunks.Dispose()
        End If

        'Write ending mark
        If attachedChunksIndefiniteCount Then
            Await str.WriteAsync({0, 0, 0, 0}, 0, 4)
        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

It does not send the request until all the data is written. Does the request buffer the stream? Does the GZipStream have effect on some kind of underling context?
I can't figure out what the problem is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was buggin' me:
Testing with a larger amount of data, the request started to send data after a coulple of chunks.

The request has a certain buffer (which you can't set working with `HttpClient`). The uncompressed content reached that limit quite soon, the compressed content obviously later.

It just looked like the whole request was buffered because my testing-data was too short.